# How does Xamarin launch your Android project?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Android projects run natively on Java, and NDK projects basically work by having a special Activity that launches your native code.  For example, [SDL has an Activity that initializes SDL, sets up a display window, and then launches your project.](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/380eae4f5059/android-project/src/org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity.java)

I'm trying to see how Xamarin does it.  Technically, CLR code is managed code rather than native, but the CLR itself is native code and the whole thing would look like an NDK project to the Android runtime.  I've been looking around, but I can't find where the Android project launcher is in Xamarin, and Googling it turns up nothing useful.

What is the mechanism by which Xamarin launches your CLR project on an Android device?

Comment: Are you looking for [Application Startup](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/#Application_Startup)?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Looks like it, yeah.  Make that into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the mechanism by which Xamarin launches your CLR project on an Android device?

You can refer to [Application Startup](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/#Application_Startup).

When an app is launched in Android device, Android will load it by specified @android:name in manifest, then usually all types will be instantiated by invoking `ContentProvider.attachinfo()` method, Xamarin.Android then here adding a `mono.MonoRuntimeProvider ContentProvider` during the build process. The `mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo()` method will then replace the native `ContentProvider.attachinfo()` method to load Mono runtime into the process.

This is how I understand that document, please advise me if there is any mistake, many thanks.

Comment: Hmm... looking at the documentation for [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html), it appears that this class is all about shared SQL data, and `MonoRuntimeProvider.java` actually makes the relevant SQL methods throw a not supported error.  So this kind of feels like a hack.  Any particular reason why this was chosen?  Is it just "thing that loads very early on in the application setup process that we're able to hook into"?

Comment: @MasonWheeler, you can check this [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html), it is not only used for share SQL data.